# When can a comparison operator ever return anything else than 0 or 1?

Tags: c

Comparison operators in C, they return either 0 for false, and non-zero for true. Is this correct?

Are there any examples where a comparison operator can return anything else than 0 or 1?

I cannot think of any so why is it possible that C can return anything else but 0 or 1? I mean (2 > 0) will always be 1. (2 == 2) will always be 1. In which cases can that ever return anything else but 1?

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Comparison operators can produce values other than 0 or 1 when there is something in the program that has behavior not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, these operators are specified by the standard to explicitly return 1 or 0. From chapter 6.5 of the standard:

**Relational operators**

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=`
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is
>   false. The result has type `int`.

**Equality operators**

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational
>   operators except for their lower precedence. Each of the operators yields `1` if the
>   specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. The result has type `int`.

Comment: It's even useful for ```Array[Base+(Value==OtherValue)*Offset]``` indexes.

Comment: @NickDoom Please don't write code like that. No bonus is paid out for writing the most operators on a single line.

Comment: Yeah, those lines of code require comments five times longer than the code itself. And they are not as human-readable as a simple ternary operator. For my taste, these tricks are OK in ```#define```, not in the main code.